# Binary addition performs type boundary checking whereas shorthand and increment doesn't

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, integer-arithmetic

I see that the below code:

```
byte b = 127;
b = b + 1;
b = b + 1;
System.out.println(b);
```

leads to boundary checking during runtime, and the first addition takes b out of range, leading to following error -

> Main.java:11: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion
>   from int to byte
>               b=b+1;
>   Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
>               b=b+1;

However, when I use the shorthand or increment, as:

```
byte b = 127;
b += 1;
b++;
System.out.println(b);
```

we find that the value of byte 'wraps around', giving the output

> -127

Why this anomaly? What actually prevents the addition from wrapping around(as C does), or increment/shorthand from doing boundary checks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this anomaly?

When you add a `byte` plus an `int` you get an `int` so when you assign it to a `byte` it complains.  However when you do

```
b += 1;
```

There is an implicit cast in this operation which is not obvious but is in the JLS.  A clearer example is

```
char ch = '0';
ch /= 0.9; // << an implicit cast occurs here.
System.out.println(ch); // 5
```

similarly, when you do

```
b++;
```

for this to compile, it has to assume an overflow is possible.

In short, the difference is that

```
b = b + 1;
```

has two operators instead of one, and this results in a warning that an overflow might occur.

Note: This doesn't apply to `int` or `long` types as you can do

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
i = i + 1; // no warning as int is not widened to long
long l = Long.MAX_VALUE;
l = l + 1; // no warning as long is the widest type.
```

Even if Java 10 might have `Long2` for 128 bit integers (and it might) `long` still won't be widened.

Comment: Very thanks, also, when doing
`short x = 10;
x = x * 5;`
I get similar sort of error - **possible lossy conversion from short to int**. 10 * 5 = 50, falls within range of short. Why is a compile time error raised? Is it because the compiler automatically casts the whole rValue to int?

Comment: @Sriram the compiler doesn't know what you know. Make the `short` or `byte` a `final` variable and the compiler can work out the warning isn't needed.

Answer (score -2):

For byte Minimum value is -128 (-2^7) Maximum value is 127 thus if greater converts to int

```
byte b  = (int) b + 1
```

Thus can not convert large int to byte